# When upgrading to USB C, can there be one USB cable to rule them all?

Tags: usb, cable, usb-3, adapter

I carry a single USB-A to USB-micro cable to connect/charge all of my devices.

USB-C and USB 3 is becoming the [new standard](https://xkcd.com/927/), so I will need to carry multiple cables or a single cable and an adapter for one of the terminators.

What are the explicit differences regarding USB-C's data transfer speed and charging speed for new devices between the following configurations?

1. A cable from USB-A male to USB-C male and a USB-C female to USB-micro male adapter
2. A cable from USB-A male to USB-micro male and a USB-micro female to USB-C male adapter
3. 2 cables and no adapter

Comment: If you are converting from USB 3 Type C to anything else then your limited by the other end

Answer (score 2):

With regard to transfer speeds, USB-C has no effect. USB-C is distinct and separate from USB 3.1/3/2/1.1 and your transfer speeds are determined solely by the capabilities of the devices communicating at either end.

1. *A cable from USB-A male to USB-C male and a USB-C female to USB-micro male adapter*

This configuration is not permitted by the USB specifications.

2. *A cable from USB-A male to USB-micro male and a USB-micro female to USB-C male adapter*

This configuration will charge and transfer data at whatever the maximum capabilities are of the least capable device, exactly the same as any other kind of USB connection.

3. *2 cables and no adapter*

This configuration will charge and transfer data at whatever the maximum capabilities are of the least capable device, exactly the same as any other kind of USB connection.

Comment: So for 2. (A cable with a micro-C adapter), does the "least capable device" include the cable? The cable I'm currently using is currently rated USB 2.0. So if I wanted to make the most of data/charge I'd want to get a better cable.

Comment: @StuperUser: USB 3.0 has additional wires, and the power wires are sized to handle more current.  You won't get USB 3.0 functionality if any part of the cable is USB 2.0 (although it will make a USB 2.0 connection).  BTW, there are length limits, so a simple adapter will work, but probably not another cable that plugs into the end of the first one.  When all is said and done, you're probably better off with dedicated cables with the right connectors.

Comment: You will get USB 2 data speeds and normal charging speeds.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old question but it seems to pop up often on searches for USB questions so I'll answer this from the point of view of someone asking this today.

> A cable from USB-A male to USB-C male and a USB-C female to USB-micro
> male adapter

Any adapter with a USB-C female port violates the USB specifications, the function of such an adapter is not defined by the spec and so there is no knowing how this will function or if it is safe to use.  DO NOT USE SUCH ADAPTERS!

> A cable from USB-A male to USB-micro male and a USB-micro female to
> USB-C male adapter

Micro-B female to USB-C male adapters are in the USB specifications only for backward compatibility to USB 2.0 devices, and so will have the "narrow" 4-pin connector.  If the adapter has 9 pins then it violates the spec and has the potential to damage hardware.  If USB 3.x data is needed then the proper thing to do is get a cable with USB-A male to USB-C male and avoid the need for an adapter.

> 2 cables and no adapter

This is the best option.  Avoid adapters if possible, the USB spec is written to keep everything safe and keep the need for adapters to a minimum.  We live in a world where there are still plenty of devices with captive cables that end with USB-A male connectors so there will be a need for USB-C to USB-A adapters.  If a device has a captive cable with a male USB-C end on it then don't try to find an adapter for it, it has a USB-C connector for a reason so don't defeat the protection this offers with an adapter that is not in the spec.

There's also power supplies in this world with captive cables with "narrow" micro-B connectors.  In the spec is the option to put a USB-C male adapter on the end for newer phones.  It's always best to avoid an adapter if possible since that is another potential point of failure.  If the cable you are looking for is only available from some Chinese dealer online then that should be a clue that you are doing something wrong.  Get quality cables from trustworthy dealers and you can avoid $700 of damage from a $7 adapter.